# How can I get NSRange from UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview, cgrect, nsrange

Hello I'm trying to calculate `NSRange` in a my text view.

I want to create text reader application but I cannot calculate NSRange value. This below image represents my textView.

How can I calculate `NSRange` size?

[image]

```
(CGRect)frameOfTextRange:(NSRange)range inTextView:(UITextView *)textView
{
    UITextPosition *beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument;
    UITextPosition *start = [textView positionFromPosition:beginning offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [textView positionFromPosition:start offset:range.length];
    UITextRange *textRange = [textView textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];
    CGRect rect = [textView firstRectForRange:textRange];
    return [textView convertRect:rect fromView:textView.textInputView];
}
```